# Cant login to newly created mysql user

Tags: mysql

I created new user using the following commands:

```
create user 'test_user'@'127.0.0.1' identified by 'test_password';
grant all privileges on database_name.* to 'test_user'@'127.0.0.1';
flush privileges;
```

But when I try to log in using this password, I'm getting access denied error.

What's wrong?

`show grants for test_user@'127.0.0.1'` command shows:

```
grant usage on *.* to 'test_user'@'127.0.0.1'
grant all privileges on 'database_name'.* to 'test_user'@'127.0.0.1'
```

And that's all.

Comment: What username and pwd u used?

Comment: test_user // test_password, they are correct

Comment: How did you try to login ? command line of phpmyadmin ?

Comment: sequel pro on osx, but I also tried via command line.

Comment: For other users works perfectly, not for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try your grant like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'test_user'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'test_password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and also try `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` while creating user.

Comment: But I want to grant him privileges to only one database

Comment: There's no need to FLUSH PRIVILEGES since you're using the GRANT statement. FLUSH PRIVILEGES is only required when modifying the grant tables directly.